# How can i find where the error is in my code

Tags: c#, error-handling

I barely touched my code, and now i get some kind of error, i can't find it.. please help ! :)

*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0101  The namespace 'RyggSäckenNy' already contains a definition for 'Program'    RyggSäckenNy    C:\Users\Ringa\source\repos\RyggSäckenNy\RyggSäckenNy\RyggsäckenKlar.cs 5   Active

*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Message IDE0060 Remove unused parameter 'args'  RyggSäckenNy    C:\Users\Ringa\source\repos\RyggSäckenNy\RyggSäckenNy\Program.cs    9   Active

*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0111  Type 'Program' already defines a member called 'Main' with the same parameter types RyggSäckenNy    C:\Users\Ringa\source\repos\RyggSäckenNy\RyggSäckenNy\RyggsäckenKlar.cs 7   Active

PROBLEMS ^

```
using System;
namespace RyggSäckenNy
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool stillRunning = true;
            string userInput = "";
            while (stillRunning)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Välkommen till Programmet! ");
                Console.WriteLine("\n[1] Lägg till ett föremål! ");
                Console.WriteLine("[2] Skriv ut innehåll! ");
                Console.WriteLine("[3] Rensa innehåll! ");
                Console.WriteLine("[4] Avsluta! ");

                int menyVal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


                switch (menyVal)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Lägg till ett föremål: ");
                        Console.Write(": ");
                        userInput = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;

                    case 2:

                        Console.WriteLine("Du angav: " + userInput);

                        break;

                    case 3:
                        userInput = "";
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        stillRunning = false;
                        break;


                    default:
                        stillRunning = false;
                        Console.WriteLine("Var snäll välj ett värde mellan 1-4 ");
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well the exception says it knows the class "program" twice. i think there is something wrong with the files included in the project. If you can't figure it out, maybe post a screenshot of the solution explorer?

Comment: search your entire solution for the following string: "class program" (without the quotes). You almost certainly have that class defined in two different places.

Comment: You appear to have two files containing Program: RyggsäckenKlar.cs and Program.cs.

Comment: Thank you Jon SKeet! I erased the wrong one in the explorer and now it works again! Cheers! <3